# how to move existing time machine backup to smb

Tags: macos, mac, backup, time-machine, smb

I have a 2 TB external usb hard drive. I have partitioned it as 1TB with NTFS and 1Tb with Mac OS Extended (Journaled). I have Time machine backups in my mac partition.

I am planning to make the external drive as NTFS NAS drive. i want to move my existing backups there. Now, there are lot of solutions out there telling how to backup to smb, which is fine. what i want to know is, if i can move my existing backup to smb and configure my time machine to continue from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just point out the high level stuff the rest can be found in the link below. So you cant just copy and paste backup files,first you have to create a disk image (*.dmg) a painfully sloooow process, then you convert this *.dmg to sparsebundle then rename the the file to [PC_NAME]_[mac_address].sparsebundle and then point your time-machine to it. That's it! The whole process took me 1 week! Anyway here is the [link](http://jason-townsend.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-transfer-local-time-machine.html)

The challenges i faced was how to write to ntfs (i used macfuse and ntfs-3gs) but later found out OSX 10.6 natively supports NTFS (u just have to enable it).Also [Safer sleep during networked Time Machine backups](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081115172028293) and of course lots and lots of research :)